# Using user input to find an element in a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, input

Okay something that should be easy is killing me. I have a list of days Monday-Sunday in a list and I need to ask a user to give a number 1-7 to show the corresponding day

I have this and it works but it seems like there should be a better way to get it done

```
days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
print('Enter a day number [1-7]: ', end="")
number=input()
if number == '1' :
    print(days[0])
elif number == '2' :
    print(days[1])
elif number == '3' :
    print(days[2])
elif number == '4' :
    print(days[3])
elif number == '5' :
    print(days[4])
elif number == '6' :
    print(days[5])
elif number == '7' :
    print(days[6])
```

Comment: `number=int(input())` and then directly index the list; i.e `print(days[number-1])`. Of course, you should wrap than in a `try-except` to mitigate values that are out of the acceptable range.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a dictionary:

```
days = {'1': 'Monday',
        '2': 'Tuesday',
        '3': 'Wednesday',
        '4': 'Thursday',
        '5': 'Friday',
        '6': 'Saturday',
        '7': 'Sunday'}

number = input()
return days[number]
```

The merit of this, over using a simple list (which works well too since you're expecting integers) is that you might later want to accept inputs that are not numeric, like `"one"`. You would just have to rename the dictionary's keys.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
number = int(input())
print(days[number - 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the @Jim Fasarakis-Hilliard You need to use `try` and `except` method to catch undesired input.

```
days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
print('Enter a day number [1-7]: ', end="")

try:
    number=int(input('enter day'))
    if number <= 7 and number > 0:
        print(days[number-1])
    else:
        raise Exception
except ValueError:
    print('must be an integer')
except Exception :
    print('number must be below 7')
```

`ValurError` will catch if number entered is not a number ,
and `raise Exception` will catch if number entered is not in range `0<n<7`